# File.Copy works on Debug mode but not on Release mode

Tags: c#, debugging, release

Something very weird happens in my WPF app. Inside the code I have two lines of code that copy two files from one place to another, like:

```
File.Copy(sourcepath1,targetpath1);
File.Copy(sourcepath2,targetpath2);
```

The weird thing is when I compile under `Debug` mode it runs great and copying the files as desired, but when I compile under `Release` mode there is no exception, all looks fine but it doesn't copy the files.

Do you have any idea what it can be?

I don't have `#If Debug` stuff inside, also I tried to clean and build the solution but it didn't help.

I also made a small test on console app, but there in both Release and debug works fine.

Comment: what are the paths? if your files are in debug folder obviously it won't work in release mode.

Comment: The short answer is, `File.Copy` does work in both debug and release mode, you need to check your privileges, paths, and code. Also rule out other apps running, virus checkers as well

Comment: How are you *running* those two versions? Is the release version maybe running as a different user that has no access to those files/folders?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing in Release, If I do `Process.Start(targetpath1);` it opens the file, but I don't see it in File explorer, that's weird, bucause same code in Debug mode, displays the file in File explorer